# Crawling for emails on websites given by Google API

Tags: ruby, http, email, web-scraping

I'm trying to build an app which crawls a website to find the emails that it has and prints them.  I also want to allow the user to type "false" into the console when they want to skip the website (maybe the user has already found 2 emails and doesn't need any more).

Is the way I'm approaching this the best way? If not, then how can I improve, and what am I missing?

```
require "nokogiri"
require "json"
require 'mechanize'
require 'anemone'
require "typhoeus"
require "timeout"

class String

    def to_bool()
        return true if self == "true"
        return false if self == "false"
        return nil
    end
end




class Query
            def initialize(keyword)
            10.times do |n|
                    num = (n * 10 + 1).to_s
                    p num
                    req = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[my_key]&cx=018020274830505137072:utuofm0ugh0&q=" + keyword + "&start=" + num, followlocation: true)        
                    res = req.run
                    File.open("file.json","w") do |file|

                    file.write(res.body)
                    end
                    continue = "true"
                    fs = File.read("file.json");
                    string = JSON.parse(fs);

                  string["items"].each do |item|
                      p continue.to_s + "<- item"

  begin 
    Anemone.crawl("http://" + item["displayLink"] + "/") do |anemone|                   
      anemone.on_every_page do |page|                           
        if continue.chomp.to_bool == false
          raise "no more please"
        end
        request = Typhoeus::Request.new(page.url, followlocation: true)
        response = request.run
        email = /[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/.match(response.body)
        if email.nil?
        else
          p email
          begin
            continue = Timeout::timeout(2) do
              p "insert now false/nothing"
              gets
            end
          rescue Timeout::Error
            continue = "true"
          end
        end                 
      end                   
    end                 
    rescue Exception => e
      p e
      continue = "true"
      next                  
    end         
    p "---------------------------------------------------------"
end

                    p "new request"


                end

            end
    end


qs = Query.new("texas+web+development")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @tokland pointed out, the major thing that jumps out when reading your code is the indentation problems. In most Ruby code you see, the standard indentation is 2 spaces. It looks like you are using hard-tabs, which are generally a bad idea. You should explore the settings of your text editor -- most have an option to insert spaces instead of tabs when you press the "tab" key. Here is your code would look like if indented properly:

```
require "nokogiri"
require "json"
require 'mechanize'
require 'anemone'
require "typhoeus"
require "timeout"

class String
  def to_bool()
    return true if self == "true"
    return false if self == "false"
    return nil
  end
end

class Query
  def initialize(keyword)
    10.times do |n|
      num = (n * 10 + 1).to_s
      p num
      req = Typhoeus::Request.new("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[my_key]&cx=018020274830505137072:utuofm0ugh0&q=" + keyword + "&start=" + num, followlocation: true)
      res = req.run
      File.open("file.json","w") do |file|
        file.write(res.body)
      end
      continue = "true"
      fs = File.read("file.json");
      string = JSON.parse(fs);
      string["items"].each do |item|
        p continue.to_s + "<- item"
        begin 
          Anemone.crawl("http://" + item["displayLink"] + "/") do |anemone|
            anemone.on_every_page do |page|                           
              if continue.chomp.to_bool == false
                raise "no more please"
              end
              request = Typhoeus::Request.new(page.url, followlocation: true)
              response = request.run
              email = /[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/.match(response.body)
              if email.nil?
              else
                p email
                begin
                  continue = Timeout::timeout(2) do
                    p "insert now false/nothing"
                    gets
                  end
                rescue Timeout::Error
                  continue = "true"
                end
              end                 
            end                   
          end                 
        rescue Exception => e
          p e
          continue = "true"
          next                  
        end
        p "---------------------------------------------------------"
      end
      p "new request"
    end
  end
end

qs = Query.new("texas+web+development")
```

For your `to_bool()` function, this might be a little nitpicky, but I would rewrite it as a `case` statement like this:

```
class String
  def to_bool()
    case self
      when "true"; true
      when "false"; false
      else; nil
    end
  end
end
```

The URL you're passing to `Typhoeus::Request.new` is ratehr long. You might consider doing something like this to shorten your line lengths a little:

```
base_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[my_key]&cx=018020274830505137072:utuofm0ugh0&q="
req_url = base_url + keyword + "&start=" + num
req = Typhoeus::Request.new(req_url, followlocation: true)
```

Or, if you want to be really diligent about not having long lines, you could do this:

```
base_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1"
key = "[my_key]"
cx = "018020274830505137072:utuofm0ugh0"
req_url = "#{base_url}?key=#{key}&cx=#{cx}&q=#{keyword}&start=#{num}"
```

You have a part of your code that goes `if email.nil?` (nothing) `else` (something). A better way to put this would be:

```
unless email.nil?
  p email
  # etc.
```

As a general note, you could make your code more concise by using less "intermediate" or "throw-away" variables. Take advantage of Ruby's method chaining and try condensing your code like this:

```
...

# No need to define a variable res; req.run is short enough
req = Typhoeus::Request.new(req_url, followlocation: true)
File.open("file.json", "w") do |file|
  file.write(req.run.body)
end

...

# You can get rid of the fs and string variables and do this: 
JSON.parse(File.read("file.json"))["items"].each do |item|
  p continue.to_s + "<- item"
  # etc.

...

# You could change the name of the variable from request to req, 
# for consistency -- you named another Typhoeus request "req"
# earlier in the code, and it doesn't look like you still need
# that variable, so there's no harm in re-using the name "req."

# Notice how you can eliminate the need for the variables "response"
# "email" like this:
req = Typhoeus::Request.new(page.url, followlocation: true)
email_pattern = /[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/
unless email_pattern.match(req.run.body).nil?
  # etc.
```

You might consider changing `if continue.chomp.to_bool == false` to `unless continue.chomp.to_bool`, or even `if continue.chomp == "false"`. In fact, I think I like the last way the best -- you could totally do away with monkey-patching a `String#to_bool` method and just compare `continue.chomp` to `"true"` or `"false"`. It's your call, of course. :)

Lastly, this is just my 2 cents, but I think you could simplify the way you're using `continue`. If I'm understanding correctly, it starts as "true" and you want the program to keep running unless the user types "false" when prompted. I would consider doing away with your `String#to_bool` method and just comparing whether or not `continue.chomp.downcase` equals `"stop"`, `"exit"` or `"quit"`. You could do something like this:

```
stop_words = ["stop", "exit", "quit"]
continue = ""

...

if stop_words.include? continue.chomp.downcase
  raise "no more please"
end
```

This would save you from having to keep doing `continue = "true"` to make sure the program doesn't stop. As long as the value of `continue.chomp.downcase` is not one of the stop words, the program will keep running.

I admit, though, that I don't really understand the use of `continue` in `p continue.to_s + "<- item"`, so maybe there is something I'm missing.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this huge and in depth answer. I must say that I will have to start indenting my code a bit better. The p continue.to_s is for debugging purposes but since this application now works I should've indeed removed it. Also the method chaining is actually quite a nice idea. The unless statement is indeed a very nice idea however I have some problems reading the code myself if I use unless however I will have to adapt :D. The case statement does indeed look more neater and the "2 cents" is I guess quite a nice way to make my program more intuitive. Thank you yet again